# LocalStorage doesn't save on refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

it is displaying the data in localStorage when I submit, but on refresh it clears the LocalStorage.

What am I missing?

Context: It is an simple todo app and the App component is the only one with localStorage or useEffect in it.

It is from the tutorial of Dev Ed on Youtube ' Build A Todo App With REACT '

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Form from "./components/Form/Form";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList/TodoList";

function App() {


  const [inputText, setInputText] =  useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("all")
  const [filteredTodos, setFilteredTodos] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    filterHandler()
    saveLocalTodos()
  },[todos, status])

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalTodos()
  },[])


  const filterHandler = () => {
    switch(status){
      case "completed":
        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === true))
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        setFilteredTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed ===false))
        break;
      default:
        setFilteredTodos(todos)
        break;
    }
  }

  const saveLocalTodos = () => {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
  }

  const getLocalTodos = () => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("todos") === null){
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    }else {
      let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
      setTodos(todoLocal)
    }
  }


  return <div className="App">
    
    <header>
      <h1>Todo - List</h1>
      <Form 
      todos={todos} 
      setTodos={setTodos} 
      inputText={inputText} 
      setInputText={setInputText}
      setStatus={setStatus}
     
      />
      <TodoList  filteredTodos={filteredTodos}  setTodos={setTodos} todos={todos}/>
    </header>
    
    
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: [useEffect documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) says _By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render._ So it is being called even without changes in `[todos, status]` (l. _on mount_) and it calls `saveLocalTodos` which saves `[]` on mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if that the todos is not empty before saving to localStorage

```
useEffect(() => {
    filterHandler()
if(todos.length !== 0)
    saveLocalTodos()
  },[todos, status])
```

Comment: It didn't work for me with your code, but I changed it below with your idea and it worked, thank you!     const saveLocalTodos = () => {
    if(todos.length !== 0){
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
    }
     
  }

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (thanks to Lah Ezcen and Jax-p):

```
    const saveLocalTodos = () => {
    if(todos.length !== 0){        //this line is new
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
    }   
    }
```

It now checks if the array is empty and if not it saves to localStorage.